# How to run bottle and a concurrent function?

Tags: python, bottle

I have a web server which creates a file upon being called. I would like to add somewhere a function, run concurently, which would check this file and act upon its contents but I do not know where to place it in the code. The code for the web server:

```
import bottle
import pickle
import time

class WebServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        bottle.route("/", 'GET', self.root)
        bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)

    def root(self):
        with open("watchdog.txt", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(time.time(), f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WebServer()
```

The function I would like to run together with the web server:

```
def check():
    with open("watchdog.txt", "rb") as f:
        t1 = pickle.load(f)
    t2 = time.time()
    if t2 - t1 > 10:
        print("stale watchdog")
```

The call to `WebServer()` puts the program into a loop (which is OK, the web server is listening) so I would like to put `check()` somewhere where it could be combined with a callback (akin to `self.root.after()` in Tkinter). How to best do this?

NB: I omitted in the code above error checking, accounting for missing `watchdog.txt`, etc. for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: "run together" - please clarify. do you want to periodically call `check`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: yes, exactly. I would like to periodically call `check()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I finally found is to use the [Event Scheduler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html):

```
import bottle
import pickle
import time
import threading

class WebServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        bottle.route("/", 'GET', self.root)
        bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)

    def root(self):
        with open("watchdog.txt", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(time.time(), f)


def check():
    try:
        with open("watchdog.txt", "rb") as f:
            t1 = pickle.load(f)
    except IOError:
        pass
    else:
        t2 = time.time()
        if t2 - t1 > 10:
            print("stale watchdog")
        else:
            print("fresh watchdog")
    finally:
        threading.Timer(10, check).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    check()
    WebServer()
```